# how to output 2 columns if i have 4 columns in postgresql and hibernate select c.name, c.email from Car c", Car.class, if

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

how to output 2 columns if i have 4 columns in postgresql using hibernate select c.name, c.email from Car c", Car.class if
public class Car {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String email;

private String lastName;}
```

Comment: This is the anwser you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71934641/2143128

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do it
One is  using [DTO Projection](https://thorben-janssen.com/dto-projections/)

Another is very simple one. Just return `List<Object[]>` and return a List of object array, you can store whatever you want.

I would suggest you to use DTO Projection if you have  JPA version  2.1 or above else go with second option.